# in_array() with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Let's say that I wanted to create an IP Blacklist system that just kills the page if their IP exists in the Database**.

Here's what I currently have:

File: index.php

```
#### Firewall ####
$data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM firewall");

if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $data->fetchAll())) {
    die("Error!");
}
#### Firewall ####
```

Database:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | ip        | date       |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 | 127.0.0.1 | 2017-05-16 |
+----+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The thing is, it doesn't seem to work at all.
Any help is appreciated.

**: I'm using **PDO** to connect to Database

Thanks,
CrAzYz_ (Zypeth)

Comment: Please see the contents of `$data->fetchAll()`

Comment: Also learn about `WHERE` clause

Comment: @u_mulder It's the same as what I shown, named "Database:". Since you asked, I'll still show it. `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [ip] => 127.0.0.1 [1] => 127.0.0.1 [date] => 2017-05-16 [2] => 2017-05-16 ) )`

Comment: It’s absolute mega nonsense to request all records from the database in such a scenario. Write a query that selects the record(s) with the remote IP instead, and then check how many result records you got.

Comment: @u_mulder I don't think `WHERE` is really needed for this purpose. Maybe lesser system load but take it as I want the whole table to be loaded into the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$block = $conn->prepare("SELECT `ip` FROM `firewall` WHERE `ip` = :ip");
$block->bindParam(':ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$block->execute();
$block = $block->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!empty($block)) {
    die("Error!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
#### Firewall ####
$data = $conn->query("SELECT `ip` FROM firewall");

if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0))) {
    die("Error!");
}
#### Firewall ####
```

It uses the [FETCH_COLUMN](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) so you only get a single column instead of an array as result.

Comment: What's the output or error of $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);?

Comment: I changed to code to specifically retrieve the IP, what does this output?

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

> PDOStatement::fetchAll() returns an **array** containing all of the
>   remaining rows in the result set. The array represents each row as
>   **either an array of column values or an object with properties**
>   corresponding to each column name.

This means that `$data->fetchAll()` isn't a one-dimensional array, but an array of records (a bi-dimensional array) or an array of objects.
So, you should do something like:

```
// Collect IP addresses in a separate array first
$ips = [];
foreach($data->fetchAll() as $record){
     $ips[] = $record->ip; // or, $record['ip']
}

// Test the remote address against the 1-dimensional array
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ips)) {
   die("Error!");
}
```

To be sure about the format of the returned data, you could just do a:

```
print_r($data->fetchAll());
```

Comment: Didn't work. I did a `print_r($ips);` just before `foreach($data->fetchAll() as $record) {}` and what I got is just `Array ( )`

Comment: Well, obviously: you just initialized $ips to an empty array. What I wrote is do `print_r($data->fetchAll());`, not $ips. If it does not work, you might want to assign the result to a variable prior to the print_r(), e.g. `$records = $data->fetchAll(); print_r($records);`